# extracting json array values from mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, database

I have data which is of type json in MySQL and column name of json data is IMEI_DATA.

```
IMEI_DATA: {"SUBSCRIBER_HISTORY": [{"IMEI": "12345678", "COUNTER": "1", "Service Flag": "7", "UPDATE_DATE_UNIX_TIME": "65667"}]}
```

I need to extract the field IMEI from it and tried with json extract query like this:

```sql
SELECT  json_extract(IMEI_DATA,"$.SUBSCRIBER_HISTORY.IMEI") FROM SUBSCRIBER_HISTORY_JSON
```

and it is giving the result as null..

Comment: you should refer to the column name that contains the JSON and not to IMEI_DATA. Then you should navigate to the nested array. You can find more details [here in the dev documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract)

Comment: The problem is that you want ```$.SUBSCRIBER_HISTORY[0].IMEI```... because you IMEI is contained in a json, as first (0) element of an array

Comment: yea..got it thank you.